# How do I create tabs dynamically with the MaterializeCSS framework and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I'm using materializecss.com. Any help is appreciated!
I'd like it to be like, when someone clicks on a button, it dynamically creates a new tab which it then moves the user to. However, I'm having issues with making this work (my code right now is worthless). How would I do this?

Thanks!

Code:

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col s12">
     <ul id="tabs" class="tabs">
         <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
         <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
         <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
         <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
  <div id="tabsCollectionDiv">
      <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
      <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
      <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
      <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
  </div>
  </div>




<script>
   function forwardFunction()
   {
       var randTabName = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
       $("tabs").append("<li class='tab col s3'><a href='"+randTabName+"'></a></li>");
       $("tabsCollectionDiv").append("<div id='"+randTabName+"' class='col s12'>""</div>");
       $('ul.tabs').tabs();
   }
</script>
```

**EDIT: Link for code: https://jsfiddle.net/6agmr9e7/1/**

Comment: Even if your code is worthless we would still like to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: api docs and source don't look like this was provided for....would try re-initializing plugin after adding and see what happens

Comment: create a simple demo . Will look for a hack on it. Assume you want the new tab to be active?

Comment: @charlietfl okay thanks

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I added a code sample in the link

Comment: @charlietfl I added a code sample in the link

Comment: @blahblah2 I am leaving work so I cannot help you out, I upvoted your question from the earlier down vote, but please also post the code on stackoverflow, its good you have a link but somepeople cannot or will not open it. for best results, post your code and give a link.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith sorry! My formatting got screwed up on here!

Comment: that code doesn't help a lot without the scripts and css needed. Use a sandbox like plnkr.co or  jsfiddle.net to create enough resources for working demo

Comment: @charlietfl there are no scripts and CSS needed aside from the cdns and stuff

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I added the code directly into SA. Thanks!

Comment: well that's what i mean... i'm not going to go find them

Comment: @charlietfl I'm sorry I'm a little confused. Sorry if I've caused you issues. However, I've only left out the cdns for Jquery, materializecss, and there is no CSS. Does that help?

Comment: so...for me to help you I should go find the cdn links myself ?  Not interested thanks. Until this question i had never even seen this framework

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, I didn't think that cdns would be the source of the problem

Comment: @charlietfl give me a few minutes to put up the whole thing

Comment: @charlietfl added the link to jsfiddle sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 1):

This version seems to work reasonably well:

```
 function forwardFunction()
   {
       var randTabName = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
       var $tabs = $('#tabs');
       $tabs.children().removeAttr('style');       

       $tabs.append("<li class='tab col s3'><a href='#"+randTabName+"'>New"+randTabName+"</a></li>");
       $("#tabsCollectionDiv").append("<div id='"+randTabName+"' class='col s12'>New"+randTabName+"</div>");

       // initalize tabs again, then select new tab
       $tabs.tabs().tabs('select_tab', randTabName);
   }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6agmr9e7/6/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! But what's the reasoning behind doing the removeAttr and and why when you initialized the tabs again did you need to write tabs twice?

Comment: needed to remove the widths that get set...and first tabs call initializes them, second one sets the active tab

Comment: so do I need to reset the widths afterwards or is it automatic?

Comment: took me a while to figure that part out but widths get set inside plugin. Plugin itself is not as mature as many others https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/js/tabs.js

Comment: Huh. Didn't see that one coming. Thanks! I wouldn't have solved it before otherwise without you.

Comment: actually can remove the `$tabs.children().removeAttr('style');   ` I was originally trying to make it work by `$tabs.tabs('select_tab', randTabName);` but without the first tabs call widths weren't being reset

Comment: have to call `tabs()` again so the widths get adjusted